# AWS Security Group - Set of port for set of IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I want to open a set of port which isn't a range, let's say, 5000, 5100, 5200, 5300, 5400, etc for a set of IPs which are different, example 111.111.111.111/32, 222.222.222.222/32, etc

From the security group interface it looks I'll have to add custom inbound rules like:

- 5000 - 111.111.111.111/32
- 5000 - 222.222.222.222/32
- 5100 - 111.111.111.111/32
- 5100 - 222.222.222.222/32
- etc

Is there a way to group any of these? So either:

- 5000,5100,etc - 111.111.111.111/32
- 5000 - 111.111.111.111/32,222.222.222.222/32

If no, the issue is that I can't add infinite number of inbound rules. So what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating security groups each for 5000 , 5100 etc say **security-group-port-5000** , **security-group-port-5100** and add the rules accordingly into that security group eg .

```
 security-group-port-5000 - inbound rules 5000 - 111.111.111.111/32,222.222.222.222/32

 security-group-port- 5100 - inbound rules 5100 - 111.111.111.111/32,222.222.222.222/32
```

You can do that using [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.authorize_security_group_ingress) also

Also, since you can add limited inbound rules, I would recommend to use IpMasking whereever possible.

AWS also provides you to add one security group into another security group also. Read [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule)